# My navbar doesn't line up in IE how can I fix without Javascript?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

My navbar doesn't line up in IE... how can I fix this without using Javascript...

http://opentech.durhamcollege.ca/~intn2201/brittains/labs/index2.php

Also it has to be able to work on all resolutions.

And it has to validate in strict.

Comment: Which version of IE, seems fine in FF and IE8.

Comment: Yeah, in IE6 it's a mess.. It's probably because of the way you have constructed the nav bar, many divs with buttons instead of text or image links, probably wise to revise this method.

Comment: well yes thats the point of this post... how might I keep the same effect without having cross browser issues...

Comment: Scrollbar is ok in Ie6 - 8, but you have some serious css fixing to do in ie6/7 since the menu is broken there.

Comment: oh and the multiple Divs are needed for "strict DTD"

Comment: well yes I know I need some fixing... but I don't know how to go about fixing it without losing that effect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put absolute position to every single button, just `position:aboslute` to the parent element (`navbar`) and for the forms (no need of a separate style for every form) just put `float:left`

Comment: changed that to position: relative and it worked brilliantly ty ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Put all the buttons inside a div, instead of using position relative on each button.

Then each button should be next to each other.

Comment: that is exactly what I did -_- and its the error I'm asking a fix for

Comment: As far as i can see you have a class for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the buttons inside one div.

You have:

```
<div id="navbar">
<form class="navbarForm1" method="get" action="index2.php">
  <div><input type="submit" value="Home" /></div>
</form>
```

Remove the nested divs. And also you're missing a closing div after your last form close.

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <form class="navbarForm1" method="get" action="index2.php">
          <input type="submit" value="Home" />
        </form>
<form class="navbarForm2" method="get" action="lab1noscript.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Lab1" />
</form>

    </div>
```

Comment: If I do that it wont validate with Strict DTD